# Accessing services field of Meteor.users

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I query `Meteor.users` I do not receive the `services` field or any other custom fields I have created outside of `profile`. Why is it that I only receive `_id` and `profile` on the client and how can I receive the entire `Meteor.users` object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the DOcs

By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are published to the client. You can publish additional fields for the current user with:

As said above If you want other fields you need to publish them

```
// server

Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'services': 1, 'others': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

// client

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer does work, but it means you have to subscribe to said data, which you should do if you are getting data from users other than the currently logged in one.

But if all you care about is the logged in user's data, then you can instead use a `null` publication to get the data without subscribing.

On the server do,

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  if (! this.userId) {
    return null;
  }

  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {
    fields: {
      services: 1,
      profile: 1,
      roles: 1,
      username: 1,
    },
  });
});
```

And this is actually what the accounts package does [under the hood](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L707)